# Slight solid line appearing in a CSS gradient? The gradient is not smooth

Tags: css, gradient

I have a page where the body is set to a background colour. I have a fixed-position footer that is above some text that scrolls behind it.

I have used a css3 gradient to attempt to create a sort of fade effect, but there seems to be a brighter line occurring somewhere along the gradient. Any tips to remove this line would be greatly appreciated. Ideally, **I would like to avoid using images as the colours are changing dynamically across various pages**, so it would be nice not to have to create a new background image for every colour.

I have created a jsbin to demonstrate:

http://jsbin.com/okedut

I also took a screenshot and increased the contrast/size in photoshop which confirms there is indeed a line appearing for some reason:

[image: Line appearing in gradient]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a browser bug when you are using rgba values.

The effect that you want to achive can be done with CSS masks.

http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

For FF you can use a SVG solution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/applying_svg_effects_to_html_content

Comment: Thank you, incredibly strange bug but I ended up going with an image afterall.